# Naming a cell using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="BuBatch", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "='Business Units'" & ActiveCell.Address
```

I am using "ActiveCell.Address because the cell changes.  But I get an error saying there is an error in the formula.  I don't know what the error is.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: remove the `R1C1` as you are giving it an A1 style address.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `ActiveCell` is on sheet "Business Units" (and that you aren't trying to set a name for the cell on sheet "Business Units" that is in the some location as the current cell on some other sheet), you can simplify your code to:

```
ActiveCell.Name = "BuBatch"
```

---

Fixing the existing formula requires the removal of `R1C1` reference type (as mentioned in a comment by Scott Craner) and the insertion of the `!` to separate the sheet name from the address, i.e.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="BuBatch", RefersTo:= _
    "='Business Units'!" & ActiveCell.Address
```

Answer (score 0):

`Range.Address` is a parameterized property. You can peek at its definition using the *Object Browser* (just hit <kbd>F2</kbd>):

[image: VBE Object Browser showing Range.Address definition]

As you can see, the definition goes as follows:

```
Property Address([RowAbsolute], [ColumnAbsolute], [ReferenceStyle As XlReferenceStyle = xlA1], [External], [RelativeTo]) As String
```

Square brackets denoting optional parameters, when you do this:

```
foo = ActiveCell.Address
```

You're actually doing something like this:

```
foo = ActiveCell.Address( _
        RowAbsolute:=True, _
        ColumnAbsolute:=True, _
        ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
        External:=False, _
        RelativeTo:=Nothing)
```

Note the `xlA1` value of the `ReferenceStyle` argument; the other possibility for it is `xlR1C1`.

If you want to assign `RefersToR1C1`, you need to supply a `R1C1` address, which involves supplying a non-default value to the `ReferenceStyle` parameter:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
    Name:="BuBatch", _
    RefersToR1C1:="='Business Units'!" & ActiveCell.Address(ReferenceStyle:=XlR1C1)
```

Or, use the default addressing style, and assign to `RefersTo` instead:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
    Name:="BuBatch", _
    RefersTo:="='Business Units'!" & ActiveCell.Address
```

---

I'd question the use of `ActiveCell` here: it implies that somewhere else in your code, you're activating that specific cell. Don't. Work with the object model instead:

```
Dim targetBook As Workbook
Set targetBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(path)

Dim target As Range
Set target = targetBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 'whatever the actual target cell is

targetBook.Names.Add Name:="BuBatch", RefersTo:="='Business Units'!" & target.Address
```